# Почему Angular отказывается слать нормальные post запросы?

Tags: post, angularjs

Почему Angular отказывается слать нормальные POST-запросы? То же самое на jQuery работает.

Например:

```
$http.post("/api/trenirovka/get_voprosi", { "db": base_id }, function(data) {
    $scope.SpisokVoprosov = data;               
});
```

Comment: Что значит "отказывается"? Вы получаете какую-то ошибку? Какую именно?

Comment: у меня php скрипт не принимает от него $db=$_GET["db"]; , а от jquery-норм. Я пробовал менять параметры на {"db": "1"} - всёравно

Comment: А почему должен быть `$_GET[]`? Разве для параметров POST запроса не `$_POST[]` используется?

Comment: Ой. Там пост. То описался. Не работает((. У меня версия 1.2 . Хотел поставить 1.3 - приложение слетело. Может в версии проблема?

Comment: Я ещё посмотрел [доки](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) по `$http.post()`: вроде как должно быть `$http.post("/api/trenirovka/get_voprosi", { "db": base_id }).success(function(data) {`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы неверно его используете.

Должно быть так:

```
$http.post("/api/trenirovka/get_voprosi", {db: base_id })
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.SpisokVoprosov = data;
    })
    *//и привыкайте обрабатывать ошибки, это очень полезно*
    .error(function (err) {
        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
    })
```

или так

```
$http({
    method: 'POST'
    url: "/api/trenirovka/get_voprosi", 
    data: {db: base_id },
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.SpisokVoprosov = data;
}).error(function (err) {
    console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
})
```

[Тут подробнее](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)